# Angular 5 bootstrap panel scroll

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having some problem with scrolling when I click link element(li) in my list.

```
 <!--List-->
      <ol>
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Cat 1</a></li>
        <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Cat 2</a></li>          
      </ol>

<!--Panel-->
      <div class="col-md-10 panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
              <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">
                Collapsible Group 1</a>
            </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
              sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad
              minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea
              commodo consequat.
            </div>
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
```

When I click on some element of my list, it's toggle then panel content but dont scroll.

Comment: Have ou tried putting an in-style `overflow-y: auto` ?

Comment: I try it but still not working. Thnaks for the answer.